# Zend framework redirect vs forward

Tags: php, zend-framework, actioncontroller

I have a form with three submit buttons. Each button may do a different action when clicked.

The first one saves the form data, the second generates a report without saving, the third saves and generates a report.

I have three actions in my controller :

- `saveAction` : handle the saving operation
- `generateAction` : handle the report generation
- `formDataAction` : called when the user clicks on either of the three buttons

I want the `formDataAction` to call the others actions passing all the data that comes from the form.

I tried redirect and failed to find any data with : `$this->getParams()`.

Anyone can help ?

Comment: Can you please put the redirect code that you are using. If possible please provide all the code that is going into that action which does the redirect. Is it Zend 1 or 2?

Comment: Provided that redirect issues a 302 http request it is not suitable for my need. I have just done a simple function call to the other actions inside the controller.

Comment: You could have possibly used 'zend forward' instead of 'zend redirect'. With forward it is an internal zend forwarding while redirect sends a redirect header, too.